# Price Set won't let me turn off auto-pay on contributions

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, price-sets, financial-types

I'm using Drupal 7.43 and CiviCRM 4.7.4., I'm trying to set up a contribution page that will let users pay a one time initiation fee, and then pay their first month dues, with the option to auto-renew the dues.

I created a financial type 'Initiation', and created a membership type for the group with auto-renew optional.  I created a price set, see the attached screen shot, where I have one field with radio buttons that has 4 initiation options, each leaves the membership type blank, sets the financial type to initiation, and sets the term to 0.  I then created another radio button field with membership options, all tied to the correct membership type.

I then created a contribution page, where I used the membership tab to connect to the price set.  However, when I got to the contribution page, it has an auto-renew option for both the initiation, and the membership.

Is this a bug?  Or am I just doing something wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur0BC.png)[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately CiviCRM doesn't cuurently have support without custom programming for doing a one time payment at the same time as setting up recurring payments.

A very simple custom CiviCRM extension built using civix could implement a postProcess hook that filters for the correct contribution page, and then creates a one time contrution from the first priceset field and a recurring contribution for the second.

Most of CiviCRM partners should be able to do this for you or refer to one who can.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, loved your book, literally saved my butt.